# emit outside from component, Or fire a livwire event outside of livewire componenet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to fire a livewire event on a button click from a normal blade file. I have tried the below things but it is working only from the component itself.

**Detail:** Basically I have the table rendered using jquery in a normal blade file,
every row in the table has an edit button, on click, a livewire bootstrap model will open with all the data, the modal is opening but not with data.
suggest me a hint or solution.

**livewire component as a bootstrap modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    //blahh
</div>
```

**table rendered using ajax response in standard blade file**

```
success: function(response) {                   
    $('tbody').html("");
    $.each(response, function(key, item) {
    str += '<tr>';
    //blahh...
    str += '<a href="#" id="' + item.id + '" onclick="window.livewire.emit({{ (''edit', '+item.id+'') }})" class="text-info mx-1 editIcon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal"></a>'; 

//need to fire event with id passed with it  everything is workable but jquery  showing error the way I write statement how to write ('openmodal', '16') correctly, 16 is a static id
    //blahh...
    str += '</tr>';
    })
    $('tbody').append(str);
)};
```

I have tried onclick method too as specified in the [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/livewire-emit-on-wireclick)  to use `window.livewire.emit` but not worked

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.livewire.emit({{ 'openmodal', '16' }})" id="' + item.id + '"  class="text-info mx-1 editIcon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editStudentModal"><i class="bi-pencil-square h4"></i></a>
```

**Edit Component**

```
class Edit extends Component
{    
    public $fname_edit, $user;
    
    public ?int $userId = null;
    protected $listeners = ['openmodal'  => 'edit'];        

    public function edit(int $userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        
        $user = User::findOrFail($userId);

        $this->fname_edit = $user->user_first_name;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to open the livewire modal from the normal blade with data to edit, or should I stick to jquery?

Comment: The problem is solved.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you've got a proper answer.